How can you explain your downvotes?
Translated:
Dear friends, I have come to you with an open heart, with an open soul. I am a chemist and I have eighteen years of education, including five years of university. However, my country and my education deserve better, as well as my knowledge of chemistry. After asking two questions (about equalizing the decomposition reaction of iron (II) nitrate, where it changes its valence, and about determining the oxidation states of the elements in potassium rhodanide/thiocyanate), I realized in my mind that there were guys with an IQ of about 150 sitting here. Perhaps even much higher.
If I get a minus on the StackExchange website, the first thing I think is that a bot (program) did it.
Well, a man did it. Why does he do it like the last coward, meanly stabbing a dagger in the back? There is no nickname for the voter, nor the reason for the minus. Each minus must be justified!
If the question is useless for one person, then fine, I understand it. For two, for ten, for a hundred. Why not consider a situation where it will be useful for the other eight billion people? Why don't people on StackExchange think about it?.. Or is ordinary people not allowed to come here at all? So, maybe it makes sense to test the level of intelligence of the incoming person when logging in to StackExchange? And do not accept people below a certain threshold. In my opinion, this will be logical. And if there is no such test, then every heart has the right to come here, every opinion is important. People are very different. Or have they all turned into the same type of robots now?.. It seems that it has not yet come to this.
Probably, there is a certain level of development here. But why are ordinary people subjected to such terrible attacks, such countless attacks? I'm also made of flesh and blood, I'm not an AI (artificial intelligence). I have certain knowledge, and I just want to learn something new, I want to expand my horizons. I would like to figure out what's what, to understand the mechanics of this site.

Original in Russian:
Английский язык для меня неродной, поэтому я буду писать по-русски.
Уважаемые друзья, я пришёл к вам с открытым сердцем, с открытой душой. Я химик, и у меня восемнадцать лет образования, в том числе пять лет университета. Однако моя страна и моё образование заслуживают лучшего, равно как и мои познания в химии.
Задав два вопроса (об уравнивании реакции разложения нитрата железа (II), где оно меняет свою валентность, и об определении степеней окисления элементов в роданиде/тиоцианате калия), я своим умом сообразил, что здесь сидят дяденьки с IQ примерно 150. Возможно, даже гораздо выше.
Если на сайте StackExchange мне ставят минус, я первым делом думаю, что это сделал бот (программа).
Хорошо, это сделал человек. Почему он это делает как последний трус, подло вонзая кинжал в спину? Нет ни ника проголосовавшего, ни причины минуса. Каждый минус должен быть обоснован!
Если вопрос бесполезен для одного человека, то хорошо, я это понял. Для двух, для десяти, для ста. Почему бы не рассмотреть такую ситуацию, когда он будет полезен для остальных восьми миллиардов людей? Почему люди на StackExchange об этом не думают?.. Или рядовым людям сюда доступ вообще заказан? Ну так, может, при входе на StackExchange имеет смысл устраивать входящему тест на уровень интеллекта? И ниже определённого порога людей не принимать. По-моему, так будет логично. А если такого теста нет, то каждое сердечко имеет право сюда зайти, каждое мнение важно. Люди бывают самые разные. Или сейчас все превратились в однотипных роботов?.. Кажется, пока что до такого ещё не дошло.
Наверное, здесь определённый уровень развития. Но почему обычные люди подвергаются таким жутким нападкам, таким бесчисленным наездам? Я тоже сделан из плоти и крови, я не являюсь ИИ (искусственным интеллектом). У меня есть определённые познания, а я как раз и хочу узнавать нечто новое, хочу именно расширять свой кругозор.
Хотел бы разобраться, что к чему, понять механику данного сайта.

You should not take it personally, the system has been designed to aggregate opinions without people having to justify every action in writing. Note you are not the first to complain.  You might check other questions on meta eg this one and more. You can look in the help center for more information on how the site works, in particular this.

If you hover mouse over downvote button, you can see "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

When I first joined Stack Overflow and then started to join Stack Exchange sites ten years ago, it was bittersweet and painful.
Even though most users may not, I can fully empathize with you. Every down vote hurt! The "silent, drive-by down votes" without comments were the worst!
What I learned about Stack Exchange over the last ten years includes the following:
Every SE site is like a different country, with a different culture because there are actually different communities of people who "live" on the sites which have evolved slightly different attitudes and traditions. In my opinion, some of them have more of a "you are not like us" aspect than others.
However: that aside, there is a much more important concept - for each site there is a certain range of question styles that the community prefers. This question is too conversational for Chemistry SE. Try to remove all the familiar talkative bits and shorten it so it's easier to read through quickly and understand

How to find the formula of a binary compound if we know the mass of solid product and the volume of escaped gas?

These two were correctly closed for the reasons given, and the down votes are probably for exactly what they are supposed to be for "little or no research effort"

How to balance this redox reaction: Fe(NO₃)₂ --> Fe₂O₃ + NO₂↑ + O₂↑ (electronic balance)? "How do I balance this equation?" You didn't mention what you tried, where you got stuck.
Mixing two solutions: how to solve such problems, is there a trick? more words this time, but still no clear evidence of research effort.

This question shows +2/-2 voting and extensive comments and your responses each time, and I see that you edited your post twice in response to comments.

How do you determine the oxidation states of elements in KSCN (potassium thiocyanate)?

It is a great example of how new users learn to ask question on a new site! Good job! If you continue down this path...

show evidence of, and explain your previous effort, explain where you got stuck
don't add too many extra words, keep it linear and easy to read
respond quickly and positively to user comments
have patience, and do not worry about some downvoting. I see the comment often "This is Stack Exchange, there's always a downvote." :-)

...then I think everything will be fine.
However, it takes time to feel comfortable in some sites; if your personality and the community's "personality" differ too much, it may always be a little uncomfortable. I see you do well in other SE sites, that's not a predictor of how well things will go in a new site like Chemistry SE. Don't expect the same experience in each site. Again, it's like moving to a new country, sometimes it is wonderful, sometimes... it just isn't. :-)

The best thing is to ignore the down vote if you think the question is reasonable. For some persistent down voters, this is their way out to vent all the anger they have collected from their environment, work and life! This is what they have to give back. Long time ago, ResearchGate also had a down vote option. They eventually deleted it. Hopefully, one day StackExchange management will also get rid of this useless option, at least from science based Q&A.
The main problem with down votes, even on reasonable answers, is that we really do not know if a high school student worrying about the next day test did not like this answer or a Nobel Prize winner thought it was a bad answer. Similarly, a highly upvoted or accepted answer does not mean it is correct.
There are plenty of examples in chemistry.
Science is not based on anonymous public opinions or opinion of the majority. In other words, there is no democracy in science, hence no sense of "votes"!
Yes, scientific papers are reviewed anonymously but we already know they rejected this paper because it was evaluated by field experts not by an angry StackExchanger random anonymous downvoter. Even this system of peer review is not perfect! A lot of useless and non-reproducible work gets published.
Every reasonable question is valid, if you don't want to answer or do not really know the answer, move on, or if you really want to help provide suggestions to improve it.
Some other SE communities, like SE Signal Processing, MathOverflow or SE Mathematics do not have this behavior. There are not too many likes or and almost non-existent dislikes. They get countless student questions on daily basis but question quality is better than Chemistry. Chemistry is studied by all and sundry. We will see a spectrum of questions.
What is better, is to delete or lock an obviously bad question.

Community deletion of questions is only possible with a -3 score iirc. It has been a long time, so here's the SE Meta post on this. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Votes are not about likes. Your attitude towards a fundamental mechanism of quality control suggests at least a misunderstanding of its purpose, if not that of the site.

Quality control is not done by masses or voting. QC is done by a few qualified specialists in the real world. I think you missed the fundamental point.

You seem to think Stack Exchange is a functional research network that should be performing peer-review of novel science. It is not. The quality control performed here is about whether a given question or answer post contributes to the creation of a repository of high-quality Q&A as determined by the standards of this community. That's all to be expected here, and that's all that can be done here. Votes are explicitly about posts meeting standards, showing future users whether the post meets the standards required or not. They are not about "likes" or "dislikes" at all.

Those arguments are inconsistent. Please define 'high-quality' and 'community.' Who is this anonymous community that decides whether a 'question shows research effort' for an upvote or whether 'this question does not show any research effort' for a downvote? Hypothetically, if we had a Stack Exchange (SE) site focused on medical Q&A, should the correct medication be determined based on the votes of an anonymous community, which could include high school students, college students, non-science majors, professional doctors, aspiring doctors, and others? The same argument applies to science.

These individuals might be voting on whether an answer is useful or if a question seems poorly researched. First, define the community, and then reconsider the strength of your arguments.

We do have a Medical Sciences SE! They are explicit and clear that they cannot and will not provide specific medical advice, because Stack Exchange is not a medical facility treating patients, just like it's not a lab producing research or peer review. It's okay to acknowledge you don't get what the site or network is, is meant for, is doing...
